# How do I configure ActiveMQ with STOMP?

Tags: python, activemq-classic, xstream, stomp, jettison

I'm using stomp.py as a client for ActiveMQ to talk to VeriFIX.
Verifix uses JMS.

There is an API topic to send commands to and a API.RESPONSE topic to receive responses.

Only the header arrives at the stomp client, but not the actual payload.

I seem to need to configure Message transformations on order for ActiveMQ to know how to serialize messages to STOMP clients.

http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html mentions XStream (XML) and Jettison (JSON)

How do I configure XStream or Jettison?

**(EDITED) SOLUTION:**

The solution is to include a 'transformation' header.

Valid values are: jms-map-json or jms-map-xml

Here is what the subscribe frame should look like.

```
SUBSCRIBE
ack:auto
destination:/topic/VERIFIX.API.REPLY
transformation:jms-map-json

^@
```

After finding this I still can't find it in the ActiveMQ documentation.

Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: A really good source for examples is the StompTest.java in the ActiveMQ src, it shows quite a few variations of the transformation headers being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide any detailed information just some general points which might help:

[Here](http://www.lancehendrix.com/techdocs/incubation/Talking%20Stomp%20to%20ActiveMQ.html) is a walkthrough including source on how someone else solved a similar scenario...

These are links including tutorials and source providing reference information on STOMP/XStream etc.:

- http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/book.html#Message_Transformation
- http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html
- http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html
- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/activemq/trunk/activemq-core/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/stomp/SamplePojo.java?view=markup

Comment: @EddyPronk you are welcome :-) the only references to `transformation:jms-map-json` I can see are in the transformation sample provided in the ActiveMQ doc and in the first link of my answer...